# Unable to take RDP of VM Runing on Azure

Tags: azure, rdp

Mistakenly changed the windows firewall setting to *Block all incoming connection including those in the allowed list*

[image: See here]

Now i am unable to take the RDP of the VM. so i can't reverse the option also

I tried reset the **RDP configuration** from the Azure portal but that also did not help..

How can i revert the change to take RDP of the VM now..??

Comment: Please see if this link helps you: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-reset-rdp/.

Comment: @GauravMantri this is the link i followed and reset the RDP Config..

Comment: Did you succeed using the link provided by @GauravMantri ?

Comment: Here is a similar article by Scott Hanselman
I don't know if it will work for you, but maybe you should give it a try and share your feedback if it helps you.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIReenablingRemoteDesktopWithPowerShellAfterYouveBlockedItWithYourOwnFirewallRule.aspx

Comment: @EmmanuelTOPE Just Tried this solution also..Didn't work unable to establish  a connection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution finally...

1) Turn off the current VM.

2) Spin Up a new VM (VM2) and attach the OS disk from VM1 as a data disk. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-attach-disk/) question for reference.

3) Boot VM2 and open registry

4) Load the registry hive from the attached OS disk of VM1. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/21788/how-to-edit-registry-hives-without-live-running) question for reference

5) Disable the firewall by looking for the following key EnableFirewall in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy` See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/371222/disabling-windows-server-2008-firewall) question for reference

6) Unload the registry hive.

7) Turn off VM2 and remove the attach disk

8) Create a new Vm withe Detached disk access via RDP

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of PowerShell DSC through Azure Automation to resolve this issue by having DSC enforce a firewall rule.

A number of components will be required though:

- Azure Automation Account
- [xNetworking](http://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xNetworking/2.8.0.0) DSC Module

You can then use the following DSC script:

```
configuration AddRdpAccess
{
param
(
    [string]$NodeName = 'localhost'
)

Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xNetworking

Node $NodeName
{
    xFirewall Firewall
    {
        Name                  = "AllowExternalRdp"
        DisplayName           = "Firewall Rule for RDP"
        Ensure                = "Present"
        Enabled               = "True"
        Profile               = ("Domain", "Private")
        Direction             = "Inbound"
        RemotePort            = ("3389")
        LocalPort             = ("3389")
        Protocol              = "TCP"
        Program               = "c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe"
    }
}
}

AddRdpAccess
Start-DscConfiguration -Path AddRdpAccess -Wait -Verbose -Force
```

From here you can use that script and load it in via the [Azure Automation UI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/automation-dsc-overview/).

Comment: All the details are above, you run it in Azure Automation.

Comment: If they are on a LAN then you can still do the DSC method but if they are purely in Azure then try the method suggested above... http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CSIReenablingRemoteDesktopWithPowerShellAfterYouveBlockedItWithYourOwnFirewallRule.aspx

Comment: In that process i am not able to get the certificate... The step2

Comment: For what reason? Are you getting an error? You know you could also provision an automation account just for this and then delete it when your done.

Comment: when i ping the domain name with powershell port..connection time out occoure...the account is with my client its hard for me to request him for that...